# Visual Studio 2015 replace ; to , in properties

Tags: visual-studio

This has been bugging me ever since! I just did a fresh install because I reformatted my laptop and just noticed this.
Can anyone help me change it back to ,?

[image: picture]

Comment: What problem do you have with that separator?

Comment: I've been used to the comma separator and it keeps on prompting me that input is invalid and it bugs me everytime...

Comment: It is localized, the SizeConverter class uses CultureInfo.TextInfo.ListSeparator.  Whether a semicolon is normal in the Philippines is something you surely know better than most everybody else here.  And the override applies, configured in Control Panel > Language

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for helping me...

Basically it chooses based on your main language in the control panel settings and to what your country is defaulted to. After changing, just restart visual studio and it should change!